# How to automate post-installation setup of a distribution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, system-installation, dot-files

As you all know, setting up a fresh installation of a distribution can be time consuming.
Manually installing and setting up various packages and apps takes a lot of time, even with all the dotfiles on hand.
Thus recently I have been wondering about whether there are any tools/best practices concerning the automation of this process?
Are there any universal tools? Or should plain ol' shell scripts (for different distros/hardware configurations) be plenty enough?

[Here's a link](https://opensource.com/business/15/3/automating-linux-install) for some more information on this topic.
Author's post-install shell script contains ~2000 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Many methods:

in the case of RHEL: chose different packages in anaconda (?) install definition

debian: have deb-installer add wanted packages.

some type of configuration management :

- cfengine
- ansible
- puppet

In the case of Solaris there was the installer daemon, force machines to boot via network at first boot and in that net boot install do deployment to the local disk and then reboot - done.

If you later on needed to modify the machine(s) (think network of workstation, not a server), modify the install server and force the machines to net boot.

Comment: From those three choices for configuration management, please choose ansible.  Salt would be a good second choice.  Then chef, puppet, cfengine would round out the "top" 5.

Comment: @chicks  considering that i use cfengine myself - why should i put ansible/puppet/chef before them ?

Comment: hint: cfengine works in an entirely different way compared to ansible - which means that cfengine is faster as soon as you need to deal with many machines and you aren't dependet on connection between the hub and the controlled machines.

Comment: You should answer this as you see fit.  I have used these tools with thousands of machines.  None of them are perfect, but some are easier to get started with, to scale, and to maintain.

Comment: Do not use a shell script. If it grows, you will have to check for each command whether it can be executed more than once without changing the actual configuration. It is much easier to use a definition that describes the _desired state_ of the installation, not the way to get there. I prefer Puppet manifests, but other configuration tools should be applicable.

Comment: @Erich The usage of an install server in the case of Solaris - at install time the whole system disk is blown away and the OS was reinstalled ie a clean slate, so as long as the shell scripts from the install server was correctly written, no trouble whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use my own scripts as well. Sure there's almost as many useful projects, `curl <my-installer> | bash`-scripts or even simple shell functions as there are Linux users out there.

I like [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) a lot and may go and use that for my next quick server/dev box setups.
Ansible et al. may help re-using community or personal/company modular system config setups.
But a simple 'cloud-init' script could do that as well, if you care for it [I do wonder if cloud-init supports doing checksums on web-content it pull in, something I would look at first].

Its a bit immature as a 'project' (and will require a confident/experienced shell user cautious of other peoples scripts) but my own 'apt-get.list' evolved into this: https://github.com/dotmpe/user-conf.
Getting setup script LoC down is something I've spend a lot of time on. If you don't spend too much time on a specific VM/container/"virtual app" system (or like Vagrant, just know what they can do) there is a lot you can do with a bit of automated shell and minimal manual copy-paste/ssh-copy-id/scp/adduser/usermod/etc. steps.

Most importantly: all this requires some structure with choices, probably a repository or server for dotfiles but also some ideas about keys and tokens, network, maybe different users and whatever component-view/abstraction you (need to) care about. I still just use cURL/GIT/Bash a lot and cloud-init can do that well. I am looking at Ansible modules/ roles as well, but the key point there is I think you should look which configuration system setup your are comfortable with. Agents or just SSH or something else maybe.